# update a List<Object> with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to add a `SELECT ALL` functionality to my grid with LINQ, but I get a compilation error.

```
List<Person_> PeopleUpdated = People.ToList().ForEach(a => a.SELECTED = true).ToList();
```

It says

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List <
>   LogoSapHrIntegration.frmXmlUpload.Person_>'

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's wrong with: `foreach(var p in People) p.SELECTED = true;`?

Comment: `People` is an `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Are you tying to change each `person`'s SELECTED field / property, or are you just trying to filter `SELECTED` people. If its the latter, its just `.Where(a => a.SELECTED)`

Comment: What is `PeopleUpdated` supposed to contain? - the list of all selected people, or the list of people that were updated to be selected (ie that weren't already selected). Or is it just a mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `List<T>.ForEach` has no return value (ie void), so you can't run `ToList()` against that. (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

`ForEach` a specific action for each item in the list (just like doing a real `for` loop).

In your case a simple for loop to select all is most efficient.

```
foreach (var person in People)
    person.Selected = true
```

Comment: It might be important to note that if OP wants to update all person in `People` a plain `foreach` loop is much simpler and more efficient.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Agreed - although the mucky bit of that is ending up with the `PeopleUpdated` list at the same time. Think the OP wants this to be a one-liner, and I'm not sure it can be.

Comment: Isn't this a "one-liner": `foreach(var p in People) p.SELECTED = true;`? According to the title OP wants to update the original list and doesn't need to create a new one.

Comment: Guys, the thing is that it's not entirely clear what he wants to do

Comment: @Leo Why isn't it clear? It's very clear to me. The OP is iterating the collection to set `Selected` to true.

Comment: i've asked the question in the main comments of what `PeopleUpdated` is supposed to end up with.

Answer (score 2):

`List<T>.ForEach` returns `void` (in your case, it changes your collection in place). `ForEach` takes an `Action<T>` and executes that on each item of your list.

See [List(T).ForEach on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The `ForEeach` method (which is not LINQ) runs an action on each item in the list, it's not used to filter out items from a list so it doesn't return a result.

Just run the method on each item; there is no result to assign:

```
People.ToList().ForEach(a => a.SELECTED = true);
```

If you wanted a new list of items where the property was changed, you would need to clone the items to make them separate from the originals:

```
List<Person_> PeopleUpdated = People.ToList().Select(a => {
  Person_ b = a.Clone();
  b.SELECTED = true;
  return b;
}).ToList();
```

(If the class doesn't support cloning, you would need to implement the `Clone` method (and preferably the `IClonable` interface).)

Comment: Why would you need to clone the items?

Comment: @Magnus: You would need to do that if you want a new list with changed values. Otherwise the items in the original list would also be changed.

Comment: I would think that is the point.

Comment: @Magnus: Perhaps, perhaps not. In the original code there was a new list as the result, I added code to show what would be needed to create such a result.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can use a normal `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var person in people)
{
   person.Selected = true;
}
```

Which is the simplest and cleanest.

If you really want to jump to hoops and use LINQ, you can use `ConvertAll`:

```
var list = new List<Person> { new Person(), new Person() };
var convertedPeople = list.ConvertAll(person => 
{
    person.Selected = true;
    return person;
});
```

Comment: I don't think he's trying to modify the list..."I am trying to add a SELECT ALL functionality to my grid"

Comment: @Leo Well, if you wanted to add a `Select all` functionality, wouldn't you want to *set* all `Selected` properties to `true`?